# Insertion sort slower than bubble sort

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting, insertion-sort

```js
Array.prototype.insertionSort = function(){
    for (var i=1, s,temp; i<this.length; i++){
         temp = this[s=i];
         while (s&&temp<this[s-1]) this[s] = this[--s];
         this[s] = temp;
    }
    return this 
}

Array.prototype.bubbleSort = function(){  
    var swapped = true;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i = 0; i<this.length-1; i++) if (this[i]>this[i+1]) {
            var temp = this[i];
            this[i] = this[i+1];
            this[i+1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
    return this;
}

var array = [1,4,4,5,6,7,5,3,5,67,7,4,3,5,76,234,24,235,24,4,234,234,234,325,32,6246,8,89,689,7687,56,54,643,32,213,2134,235,346,45756,857,987,0790,89,57,5,32,423,54,6,765,65,745,4,34,543,43,3,3,3,34,3,63,63,35,7,537,35,75,754,7,23,234,43,6,247,35,54,745,767,5,3,2,2,6,7,32,3,56,346,4,32,32,3,4,45,5,34,45,43,43],

    iter = 10000000;

console.time("bubble x"+iter);
for (var i = iter; i--;) array.bubbleSort();
console.timeEnd("bubble x"+iter);

console.time("insertion x"+iter);
for (var i = iter; i--;) array.insertionSort();
console.timeEnd("insertion x"+iter);
```

The insertion sort should be quicker, right? Is there something wrong with an implementation of mine?

> bubble x10000000: 3131ms
>
> insertion x10000000: 4287ms

I didn't even apply the optimisation, to the bubble sort, that decrements the loop length every iteration.

Comment: bubble 2.7s and insertion 2.3s here so I'd say it depends on internal optimization quirks of js engine. You should have used the original array for both algos in each iteration `array.slice().bubbleSort();` and `array.slice().insertionSort();` in which case insertionSort is 4x faster.

Comment: ...(4x with slice() so once its time is subtracted the difference should be much bigger).

Comment: I didn't notice that I hadn't re-assign/copy the array! Obvious hole in my testing